# How are RPs being prevented from performing unauthorized operations in the user's name?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, openid, openid-connect

I want to use `OpenID Connect` to allow users to use two separate services while maintaining the users' passwords only in one place.

Say banking service A allows users with a web browser to

1. look at their account balance
2. do bank transfers.

For above actions, service A always has to go through the API provided by service B. B also maintains all the passwords.

Say B cannot trust A and wants to make sure that every one of the bank transfers is OK'ed by the user. Reading out the account balance however should be possible arbitrarily as long as the session is running.

How can this be done in OpenID Connect?

The most secure way would be to have the user accept the specific bank transfer details and the user's browser then sign the whole content of the bank transfer so that service A can only forward that to service B.

Another, less secure way, would be to have some time-limited "transaction" scope/claim that permits service A do perform a transaction in the time window from the user's (blank check) authorization until it expires.

Is any of the above easy to implement using OpenID Connect?

Answer (score 1):

One could define per-transaction scopes so get the user's consent for a transaction, service A would have to redirect the user to service B with an OpenID Connect authentication request that includes the transaction scope. The access token that is then returned from the Provider would allow only for that transaction, which may be identified by a transaction ID that references accounts, sum, expiry window etc.

Comment: That transaction id you mention, what would that be in practice? A "one-time scope"?

Comment: I see. And service B could probably be programmed to display the transaction information in a way easily readable by the user. So it looks like what I'm trying to do is easily possible in a secure manner - I just wonder why google yields no results for "one-time scope" and "one-time claim" in connection with "openid connect" or "oauth". This would seem to be a use-case for a number of companies...

Comment: I think it is a rather unexplored territory but it fits perfectly within the scope (!) of OAuth 2.0 (rather than OpenID Connect).